# matplotlib scatter plots do not display when populated using for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to write a function to produce Matlab style correlation plots using matplotlib in Python 3.4 (example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html?refresh=true)). However, I want to change the plot so that the diagonal subplots display the name of the variable, the lower triangle subplots display the Pearson correlation coefficient, and the upper triangle subplots display a scatter plot. Below is some code to generate sample data and the function I wrote. It displays the appropriate 4x4 grid of subplots with variable names and correlation coefficients in the correct place, but the scatter plots do not show up.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

means = [0, 1, 0, 2]
sig = [[1, 0.5, 0, -0.1], [0.5, 3, 0, 0.2], [0, -0.1, 1, -0.3], [-0.1, 0.2, -0.3, 1]]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, sig, 50)
names = ['Var' + str(i) for i in range(data.shape[1])]

def corrplot(data, names):
    corrMat = np.corrcoef(data, rowvar = 0)
    numVars = data.shape[1]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(numVars, numVars, sharex = "col", sharey = "row")
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0, hspace = 0)

    for i in range(numVars):
        for j in range(numVars):
            if i == j: # On the diagonal
                ax[i, j].text(0.5, 0.5, names[i], transform = ax[i, j].transAxes)
            elif i < j: # In the upper triangle
                ax[i, j].scatter(data[:, i], data[:, j], marker = '.')
            elif i > j: # In the lower triangle
                ax[i, j].text(0.5, 0.5, str(round(corrMat[i, j], 3)), transform = ax[i, j].transAxes)
    plt.show()
```

In an attempt to identify the source of the problem, I manually reconstructed the plot for a 2 variable case using the following code, which produces the desired plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex = "col", sharey = "row")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0, hspace = 0)
ax[0, 0].text(0.5, 0.5, 'Var0', transform = ax[0, 0].transAxes)
ax[0, 1].scatter(data[:, i], data[:, j], marker = '.')
ax[1, 0].text(0.5, 0.5, '0.5', transform = ax[1, 0].transAxes)
ax[1, 1].text(0.5, 0.5, 'Var1', transform = ax[1, 1].transAxes)
plt.show()
```

Since this works, I hypothesized that the problem had nothing to do with mixing text and data in the subplots. I wrote the next function to test populating the subplots using a for loop, and it produces a scatter plot in each subplot as expected.

```
def test1(data):
    numVars = data.shape[1]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(numVars, numVars, sharex = "col", sharey = "row")
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0, hspace = 0)

    for i in range(numVars):
        for j in range(numVars):
            ax[i, j].scatter(data[:, i], data[:, j], marker = '.')
    plt.show()
```

Next, I tried to populate only a subset of the subplots using for loops. This produces a blank grid as follows.

```
def test2(data):
    numVars = data.shape[1]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(numVars, numVars, sharex = "col", sharey = "row")
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0, hspace = 0)

    for i in range(numVars):
        for j in range(i + 1, numVars):
            ax[i, j].scatter(data[:, i], data[:, j], marker = '.')
    plt.show()
```

This leads me to believe that there is some error related to the for loops and how the scatter plots are being created, but I haven't been able to find the error yet.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!  Kudos for creating a MCVE, it is much appreciated.  It's not 100% functional, however, you need to change the definition of names to `names = ['Var' + str(i) for i in range(data.shape[1])]` (string to 'str' and you forgot the `range`).  Once I did that and added a call to 'corrplot', I actually got the result to work just fine.  What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I'm using matplotlib 1.4.3. I use the Anaconda distribution and updated everything yesterday to make sure an old version wasn't the issue.

Comment: Do you have any changes to the default rcParams?  That's the only other thing I can think of that might make those dots disappear.  Try putting `plt.rcdefaults()` at the top and see what you get.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to rcParams. Adding that at the top didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit at a loss then ... even your 'test2', which is blank for you, looks like it's supposed to for me.  What backend are you using, what OS?

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.2. I have a Ubuntu server I could try it on as well. Do you think it's an OS issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that would be one of the only differences between you and me .... I'm also using Anaconda, I updated to the same matplotlib version, and it still works - I'm on Windows 7 64-bit with the Qt4Agg backend.

Comment: I've tried changing the backend from default to Agg and Qt4Agg on both OS X and Ubuntu. Still no scatter plots. This is really bizarre.

Comment: On OS X, though with Python 2.7.6, `test2` produces six scatterplots (upper right triangle) for me, and `corrplot` has those scatterplots in the upper-right and values between -1 and 1 in the lower-right.

Comment: @cphlewis Thanks, that helps narrow down the possibilities. The code is definitely correct, but it doesn't execute correctly in my environment. Sounds like it's coming down to a version compatibility issue perhaps.

Comment: Do you have a 2.7 system install or such to try on?

Comment: I can set one up. It's just inconvenient since I do all of my coding in 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows exactly the desired plot.
I think your version of `matplolib` didn’t recognize the `marker = '.'`

You could try to plot with default marker (without `marker = '.'`) or replace it with `marker = 'o'`

Comment: Ultimately I found a different solution that didn't use matplotlib. However, revisiting this with a newer version of matplotlib, it works perfectly. Thanks for the answer; it made me revisit this and realize that it actually does work.